# Download list of sites form google custom search engine

Tags: google-search-console

Does anyone know of a way to download the list of sites/URL's from googles custom search engine console? We have a list of over 500 URL's and we are wanting to download them into a CSV for review. I'm logged into the configuration page/console, but am not seeing anywhere where I could download the list of sites.

Comment: Which programming language you will use for it?..just curious

Comment: I was hoping there might be a way to do it through the UI. Using the API would be a plan B.